# check for user input data in dynamically added ComboBoxes

Tags: vba, excel, user-interface, ms-word

I am using a user form to display the acronyms found in a document and the definitions of the acronyms. Because i won't know in advance how many there will be I have created all of the labels, check boxes and comboBoxes dynamically using the for loop below.

I am now stuck in that I want to allow the user to be able to type in the comboBox a new definition is for example one didn't exist in my excel database or they want to use a different definition to the one that is there (I am aware this is bad practice but unfortunately people don't stick to the standard list). Now that all works fine with it set up as it is however my problem is that I want to check if the user has entered something new or not.

So my question is, is there a built in function or variable that does this? or is there a simple way to do it? (I already have tried and tested the code to add the string to my database so that is not an issue, just the checking if it wasn't there before without running through the entire database from scratch again)

```
    For i = 1 To n

        checkBoxi = "CheckBox" & i
        labeli = "Label" & i
        comboBoxi = "ComboBox" & i

        'add checkbox, label and combobox
        .MultiPage1.Pages("Page1").Controls.Add "Forms.CheckBox.1", checkBoxi
        .MultiPage1.Pages("Page1").Controls.Add "Forms.Label.1", labeli
        .MultiPage1.Pages("Page1").Controls.Add "Forms.ComboBox.1", comboBoxi

        'position check box
        .MultiPage1.Pages("Page1").Controls(checkBoxi).Left = LeftSpacing
        .MultiPage1.Pages("Page1").Controls(checkBoxi).Top = TopSpacing + rowHeight * i

        'position labels
        .MultiPage1.Pages("Page1").Controls(labeli).Left = LeftSpacing + 15
        .MultiPage1.Pages("Page1").Controls(labeli).Top = TopSpacing + 2 + rowHeight * i
        .MultiPage1.Pages("Page1").Controls(labeli).Caption = acronyms(i - 1)
        .MultiPage1.Pages("Page1").Controls(labeli).Width = 70

        'position comboBox
        .MultiPage1.Pages("Page1").Controls(comboBoxi).Left = LeftSpacing + 100
        .MultiPage1.Pages("Page1").Controls(comboBoxi).Top = TopSpacing + rowHeight * i
        .MultiPage1.Pages("Page1").Controls(comboBoxi).Width = 300

'find definitions for comboBox
    ' Find the definition from the Excel document
    With objWbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
        ' Find the range of the cells with data in Excel doc
        Set rngSearch = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A" & .rows.Count).End(-4162))

        ' Search in the found range for the
        Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=acronyms(i - 1), After:=.Range("A1"), LookAt:=1)

        ' if nothing is found count the number of acronyms without definitions
        If rngFound Is Nothing Then


            ' Set the cell variable in the new table as blank
            ReDim targetCellValue(0) As String
            targetCellValue(0) = ""

        ' If a definition is found enter it into the cell variable
        Else

            targetCellValue(0) = .Cells(rngFound.Row, 2).Value
            'MsgBox (targetCellValue(0) & " " & 0)
            firstAddress = rngFound.Address


            Do Until rngFound Is Nothing
                Set rngFound = rngSearch.FindNext(After:=rngFound)

                If rngFound.Address = firstAddress Then
                    Exit Do
                ElseIf rngFound.Address <> firstAddress Then
                    j = j + 1
                    ReDim Preserve targetCellValue(0 To j) As String
                    targetCellValue(j) = .Cells(rngFound.Row, 2).Value
                    'MsgBox (targetCellValue(j) & " " & j)

                End If
            Loop

            End If
        End With

        Dim k As Integer
        For k = 0 To j
            .MultiPage1.Pages("Page1").Controls(comboBoxi).AddItem targetCellValue(k)
        Next k
        j = 0

     Next i
```

Comment: This post of mine might be helpful: http://yoursumbuddy.com/prompt-to-add-new-items-to-combobox-or-data-validation/

Comment: I have these comboBoxes in a pop out user form not in excel itself. I did however look into that concept and there is a property `Controls(comboBoxi).MatchRequired = True` which is similar i think however this simply prevents me from entering a value that wasn't in the drop down options. Is it possible to set the on error even for this to add it to the list and store it?

Comment: In that post the `Comobobox` is also in a (very tiny) userform. It assumes you're saving the list in an Excel table. You might try downloading the sample workbook and fooling with it. Sorry, I can't spend more time right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it. The value typed in by a user is not automatically included in the comboBox list therefore you can check it against the list to see if it was there before.

code:

```
For intComboItem = 0 To .MultiPage1.Pages("Page1").Controls(comboBoxi).ListCount - 1

   If .MultiPage1.Pages("Page1").Controls(comboBoxi).Value = .MultiPage1.Pages("Page1").Controls(comboBoxi).List(intComboItem) Then
      newDef = False
      Exit For
   Else
      newDef = True
   End If

Next

If newDef Then
   MsgBox ("new def: " & .MultiPage1.Pages("Page1").Controls(comboBoxi).Value)
End If
```

Comment: Only slightly better: `newDef = True` `For intComboItem = 0 To ..` `If .. = .. Then` `newDef = False` `Exit For` `End If` `Next`